# Invalid backend model specified: catalog/product_attribute_backend_media while overriding Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media

Tags: magento

Thanks to this article [Add a checkbox to product image gallery (like "Disable/Exclude")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297460/add-a-checkbox-to-product-image-gallery-like-disable-exclude) I was able to add new checkbox to product media gallery in magento backend. First I did this changes in magento core and they worked like a charm :) then I decided to override them with my own module like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <My_Gallery>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </My_Gallery>
</modules>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <my_gallery>
            <class>My_Gallery_Helper</class>
        </my_gallery>
    </helpers>
    <models>
        <my_gallery>
            <class>My_Gallery_Model</class>
        </my_gallery>
        <my_gallery_resource>
            <class>My_Gallery_Model_Resource</class>
        </my_gallery_resource>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_attribute_backend_media>My_Gallery_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media</product_attribute_backend_media>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
        <catalog_resource>
            <rewrite>
                <product_attribute_backend_media>My_Gallery_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media</product_attribute_backend_media>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog_resource>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <my_gallery>
            <class>My_Gallery_Block</class>
        </my_gallery>
    </blocks>
    <resources>
        <my_gallery_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>My_Gallery</module>
                <class>My_Gallery_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </my_gallery_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
```

[image]

but after doing that I'm getting an error from subject that is: exception 'Mage_Eav_Exception' with message 'Invalid backend model specified: catalog/product_attribute_backend_media'

What could be the problem?

Regards,

Comment: can you show your model files ?

Comment: Check your logs to see if you have any failed includes happening. In my case, my XML was not properly defining the model, so magento was trying to load it from the Mage/ namespace:

ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/YOUR_NAMESPACE/YOUR_MODULE/Model/Entity/Attribute/Backend/Customergroups.php' for inclusion in my_document_root/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to have a little bit more information about where you put that code to answer regardly.

It means that it cannot find the model. So it can come from the fact that the tree of your module is not correct, your config.xml does not correspond to the reality, you did not named correctly your nodes and many other reasons like that.

Other issue can be that you did something uncorrect in the database.

Is there still an attribute with backend_model named **catalog/product_attribute_backend_media** in the table eav_attribute in you database ?

Regards

Comment: Hi. I did everything that was in the link I posted. I did this changes in core folder and it was working fine. Then I move this changes to my own module by overriding them in config.xml. Full config.xml in updated post.

Comment: can you post the architecture of your module folder ?  I believe the mistake is within.

Comment: the model's names have to be like the architecture. that means that the folder in which you have the folder gallery has to be named "My"... I believe that you use something like the name of your company if you followed the naming recommandations of Magento.

Comment: There are many others modules in namespace 'My' that is why you see only 'Gallery'

Comment: can you post the stack trace ?

Comment: Do you try to extend the Models or you just erase them ? If second, try consider the first solution !