# Multiple Base Image Magento

Tags: image, magento, radix

Is there any way, where I can upload multiple images for a Single Attribute.

In fact I want to achieve like, A product will have six type of attributes, Three are there in magento, Rest three will have more images than one. So i want to create checkbox instead radion button, and those all the values will be saved and fetched in Front End.

Can any one have idea how can i do programatically in magento 1.9

Comment: Please post magento related question on 
http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36777/multiple-base-image-magento

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297460/add-a-checkbox-to-product-image-gallery-like-disable-exclude


This helped me finally

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297460/add-a-checkbox-to-product-image-gallery-like-disable-exclude